# Macro definition in c

Tags: c, macros

I was asked to implement malloc and free.. I implememented those in my malloc.c file which includes malloc.h file and in malloc.h file I have these macro

```
 #define malloc( x ) mymalloc( x, __FILE__ , __LINE__ )
 #define free( x ) myfree( x, __FILE__ , __LINE__ )
 #define calloc( x,y ) mycalloc( x, y, __FILE__, __LINE__ )
```

Whenever I use malloc(10) or something in my main function, it says undefined reference to mymalloc

Comment: gonna need a little more code than that buddy

Comment: @RedAlert Should I post malloc.c ?

Comment: Where is the code for mymalloc, myfree, mycalloc?  Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  Remember you are asking people to spend their time on your problem.  Help us help you.

Comment: malloc.h and the main function where you use the macros should be enough.

Comment: Well if this if an "undefined reference" I think code won't help much, as this seems like a linker error. So you should probably present a way how you build your stuff too.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux (or cygwin under Windows), using `gcc test.c malloc.c -o test`, the following will work (execution with `./test`)

**test.c**:

```
#include "malloc.h"
int main()
{
   malloc(10);
   return 0;
}
```

**malloc.h**:

```
#define malloc( x ) mymalloc( x, __FILE__ , __LINE__ )
int mymalloc(int x, char *file, int line);
```

**malloc.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mymalloc(int x, char *file, int line)
{
  printf("%s, line %d: %d", file, line, x);
  return 0;
}
```

*EDIT*: added the prototype of mymalloc to avoid a warning

Comment: This shouldn't work without an error, or at least a warning, because `malloc.h` doesn't include a declaration for `mymalloc()`.  Does it compile for you with no errors or warnings?

Comment: @DaleHagglund this works just fine! You can compile it and run it...

Comment: of course it is a better practice to add the prototype but it was not the problem of @user3100209

Answer (score 0):

Note that a line like

```
p = malloc(10);
```

is expanded by the C preprocessor to

```
p = mymalloc(10, "this-file-name.c", /* current line number */);
```

and this line fails to compile because there's no declaration for `mymalloc()` visible to the compiler.  You need to add the following lines to `mymalloc.h`.

```
void *mymalloc(int, const char *, int);
void myfree(void *, cont char *, int);
void *mycalloc(int, int, const char *, int);
```